# Converting schedule definition into English

Tags: php, cron, schedule

I am trying not to re-invent the wheel, and thus I am looking for a way to convert a schedule (such as say crontab format) into readable English, much like Google Calendar has. Is there something (preferably written in PHP) that could do that?

Comment: The phrase is "re-invent the wheel". Actually _inventing_ the wheel (i.e., the first time) was a damn _good_ idea.

Comment: @paxdiablo: Well... the wheel has already been invented. So all present inventing of wheels is re-inventing. =P

Comment: good point, thnx. though still inventing wheels in our day and age is not particularly inspiring task...unless it's these other wheels ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [crontab2english](http://interglacial.com/~sburke/pub/crontab2english.html), which you might find interesting, although it is not in PHP.